# eclipse shortcut for enabling / disabling JAVA breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, eclipse-jdt

I'm looking for a shortcut to completely enable / disable **all** JAVA breakpoints (analogue of pushing the "Skip all breakpoints" button in Debug view ), not to enable / disable them on a row-by-row basis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to assign your own keyboard shortcut to the `Skip All Breakpoints` command.  Use `Preferences>General>Keys` preference page to do it.

PW

Answer (score 21):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shft</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shft</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to open key assist for all possible keyword combinations.

Comment: fwiw Cmd+Shift+L for Mac OS to open key assist for all possible keyword combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is this shortcut that allow you to toggle breakpoint in the current line:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shft</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: Its not an answer. Question is about enabling/disabling `All break point` at once not single one. `Ctrl + Shift + B` toggles i.e adds/removes but NOT enables/disables breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, in debug perspective, you have a blue crossed circle, to enable/disable all breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Follow following Steps:

1. Open Preferences form `Window->Preferences`.
2. Select `General->keys`.
3. You can find `Skip All Breakpoints` or search it.
4. Select  `Skip All Breakpoints`.
5. Choose your key Binding.
6. Choose when.
7. click `Apply`.

[image]