# Disable eclipse breakpoint shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is there any shortcut to disable java breakpoint in eclipse? There is one to disable them all but I want only one of them.

This question is not about disabling all breakpoints (as in [eclipse shortcut for enabling / disabling JAVA breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053904/eclipse-shortcut-for-enabling-disabling-java-breakpoints)) but only one of them.

Also I'm aware of Eclipse debug view - but I want to use keyboard shortcut instead of going into it.

Comment: @check my screen-shot

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of ["eclipse shortcut for enabling / disabling JAVA breakpoints"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053904/eclipse-shortcut-for-enabling-disabling-java-breakpoints). That question is about skipping **all** breakpoints, which is done with `ctrl+alt+B`. This question is about disabling (not toggling or removing) a single breakpoint with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Well, the mods wouldn't remove the Duplicate label, so I'll post the answer in this comment: There's no way to make a direct keybinding, but you can use this key sequence: `ctrl+F10, D`. `ctrl+F10` opens the View Menu, `D` selects the Disable Breakpoint command.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Debug View > Breakpoints > Disable

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box shortcut for a single breakpoint is to have the cursor on the line in question and use Ctrl+Shift+B to toggle the breakpoint on and off.

Otherwise, you can set up your own shortcut using Window->Preferences->Keys.

Comment: Question is about how to disable not how to toggle

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to debug perspective, will have to click on break points.

[image]